# How to calculate average using power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

In power bi i have 2 table

Table 1 (Total no of seats)
Venue 1   100 seats
Venue 2   150 seats

Table 2 (No of seats used)
Venue 1  40 seats
Venue 2  75 seats

I need to calculate how to many seats used

ex (40/100) *100 = 40%

Can someone helps me

**Current database i can't join these table

Try to use average function did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your tables look like this:

*Table 1:*

```
Venue    | Total Seats
-----------------------
Venue 1  |         100
Venue 2  |         150
```

*Table 2:*

```
Venue    | Seats Used
----------------------
Venue 1  |         40
Venue 2  |         75
```

Create a relationship between `Table 1` and `Table 2` on field `Venue`, then you can create a measure:

```
Seat Utilisation = 
DIVIDE ( 
    SUM ( 'Table 2'[Seats Used] ),
    SUM ( 'Table 1'[Total Seats] ),
    BLANK()
)
```

See https://pwrbi.com/so_55470616/ for an example PBIX file